# Input value change is not reflected on other elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Input fields are set up to reflect upon the changes from the sliders. But the changes from the input fields are not reflected when sliders are used. It only works when I explicitly change the value of input fields.

So, (changing input value explicitly -> reflect changes) but (slider value change -> input field value changes -> this change is not reflected).

```
var rSlider = document.querySelector("#r");
var gSlider = document.querySelector("#g");
var bSlider = document.querySelector("#b");

var rInput = document.querySelector('#rInput');
var gInput = document.querySelector('#gInput');
var bInput = document.querySelector('#bInput');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(rInput).val(0);
  $(gInput).val(0);
  $(bInput).val(0);
})

$(rSlider).on('input', function() {
  $(rInput).val($(this).val());
})

$(gSlider).on('input', function() {
  $(gInput).val($(this).val());
})

$(bSlider).on('input', function() {
  $(bInput).val($(this).val());
})

$(rInput, gInput, bInput).change(function() {
  rValue = String($(rInput).val());
  gValue = String($(gInput).val());
  bValue = String($(bInput).val());
  var tempString = `rgb(${rValue},${gValue},${bValue})`
  console.log(tempString)
})
```

Again, console.log is only printed in first case but not in the second case. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is on input event? If your slider has <input> tag then its fine but if not then I think on input event shouldn't be there

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Yes, it has an input tag. It also has a type range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function changeColor(arr) {
    $("#resultColor").css("background-color", "rgb(" + arr.join(",") + ")");
  }

  function getValues() {
    return [
      $("#r").val(),
      $("#g").val(),
      $("#b").val()
    ];
  }

  $("input[type='range']").on('input change', function() {
    var i = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#" + i + "Input").val($(this).val());
    changeColor(getValues());
  });

  $("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    var i = $(this).attr("id").substring(0, 1);
    $("#" + i).val($(this).val());
    changeColor(getValues());
  });

  changeColor(getValues());
});
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  width: 2em;
}

label {
width: 60px;
display: inline-block;
}

#resultColor {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top: 10px;
  left: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <label>Red</label> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" id="r" /> <input type="text" id="rInput" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Green</label> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" id="g" /> <input type="text" id="gInput" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Blue</label> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" id="b" /> <input type="text" id="bInput" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div id="resultColor"></div>
</div>
```

In the future, it is best to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

This may be best handled by some helper functions to help get the values or set the values. Also, if you're doing the same thing 3 times, see if you can condense it into one function.

You might also consider an example from jQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker

The HTML Range Input is hard to style. The jQuery UI one is much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't used Stackoverflow much but yes I'll remember to show an example next time.